# Comparing CNNs with same training data but different number of classes

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I train a CNN image classifier for classes `tabby cat`, `tiger cat` and `dog`. Since `tabby cat` and `tiger cat` are subcategories of `cat`, I also train a classifier for the classes `cat` and `dog`. Finally, I want to compare both classifiers performance-wise.

I need to have a balanced dataset, i.e. each class has the same number of samples. This is easy implementable for the first classifier. But how do I approach this for the second classifier, given that I want to train both classifiers on the same samples? If I just put all `cat` samples together I would have twice the number of samples for this class compared to `dog` and the dataset is not balanced anymore. If I ranomly prune my `cat` samples, the second classifier wouldn't have as many samples to learn from and wouln'd be comparable to the first one.

Comment: why do you need a perfectly balanced dataset?

Comment: It doesn't have to be perfectly balanced, but twice as much data in one class sure has an influence on classification quality(?)

Comment: presumably you'd evaluate the 3-class classifier on it's ability to separate (dog) from (tabby cat, tiger cat), to have a quantity that's comparable with your 2-class model -- so in that case, the 3-class classifier is exposed to the same imbalance, so it seems a fair comparison.